# How to setup ejabber client on my server instead of localhost?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

i am currently working on xmpp to make a chat application.
by this tutorial :

[How to setup ejabber client on localhost](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958)

but i am able to test only on my simulator becuase of localhost.
i am not able to check online buddies.
so need i to setup ejabber on server? and if yes than how to install it on server?

can you please answer me?
waiting for a positive answer.

Comment: Your question is definitely too broad. You should however start by reading ejabberd installation and configuration: http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/installation/

Comment: means instalatiion should be in server side?

Comment: Well, no necessarily on a server, but it should be configured in a way that another machine can access it from the network (using correct IP for example).

Comment: yes thats i want bro.thanks

Comment: can you please also answer why turn connection failes?

Comment: Question is too broad and too generic with no details. It is impossible to help you. Please, narrow down your questions if you expect to get help on StackOverflow.

Comment: doc is too trickey to understand

Comment: If you prefer to focus on client development, you can always outsource management of the ejabberd platform to a service like https://www.ejabberd-saas.com/

Answer (score 0):

For this , you can create a server on Amazon ( as i gone through same issue and i solved using Amazon EC2 instance ).

Here is requirement :

- Amazon EC2 instance
- 2 GB Storage
- Custom Rule for HTTP having 5280 as port number

Now , you have `<ip-address>:5280`

Now just Install Ejabbered Application (in case of MAC , e mark logo app)  download and just click it , it will install it , and then when it ask for server then just pass your server .

After configuring Ejabberd Server just use ,
bin/ejabberdctl status 
bin/ejabberdctl start

Now you having :

```
<ip-address>:5280/admin 
username
password
```

Now if just hit on URL , it will ask 
User Name 
Password

then navigate to Web Admin panel where you can find :

- Access Rule
- Users
- Online User etc

**NOTE** - if on url not working then you need to whitelist this server id and open port (5280,5222,5282,5269) and also check firewall setting.

After dealing with 15 days finally we solved this.
Hope this gonna help you.